# How to call a python class like calling a function

Tags: python, function, class

Searching to build up my personal style of programming i want to be able to call a python class the same way i'd call a python function.
Here's what i mean:
consider this function:

```
def Factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * Factorial(n - 1)
```

This is a function that outputs 24 when you call Factorial(4).

Now let's consider a class instead:

```
class Factorial:
    def __call__(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * Factorial()(n - 1)
```

This code works the same way as the previous code except at call time where you instead write:

```
Factorial()(4) # which outputs 24
```

Now my question is how could you do this instead:

```
Factorial(4) # just that, and output 24, from THE object.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why?  Calling the `Factorial` class should return an object with type `Factorial`.  You *can* do this, using metaclasses to give the `Factorial` class a different `__call__`, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: OP, I think you need to understand the purpose of a Class and the purpose of its inherent encapsulation.  A Class is not the same as a function.  That being said, to make use of the constructor of a class, you should define `__init__` so you can pass the appropriate information into it in order to process, and could then kick off the processing in that function.

Comment: Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51448410/820410)  . If it solves your purpose, please accept/up vote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self`.

```
class Factorial:
    def __call__(self, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * self(n - 1)

f = Factorial()

f(3)
# 6
f(5)
# 120
```

From there you can easily add a starting value in your `__new__` constructor.

```
class Factorial:

    def __new__(cls, value=None):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        if value is None:
            return instance
        else:
            return instance(value)

    def __call__(self, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * self(n - 1)
```

Now you can

```
Factorial(5)
# 120
f = Factorial()
f(5)
# 120
```

Comment: Very nice work. You made sure that the normal functionality of a class doesn't break, and added the functionality i asked for. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor (which is __init__ in Python) like so:

`class Factorial:
    def __init__(self, n):
        // code here`

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method:

```
class Factorial:
    def __new__(cls, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * Factorial(n - 1)
```

Although the above solution works, I prefer a decorator-based solution which is less magical and is more intuitive and explicit:

```
def function_factory(cls):
    return cls()

@function_factory
class Factorial:
    def __call__(self, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * Factorial(n - 1)
```

Comment: This works and is the most elegant solution that feels natural. I take this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A short & simple change in your existing code:

```
>>> class Factorial:
...     def __call__(self,n):
...             if n == 0:
...                     return 1
...             else:
...                     return n * self.__call__(n - 1)
... 
>>> Factorial = Factorial()
>>> Factorial(4)
24
>>>
```